# Water is way past the max level line on airlock

Tags: airlock

Will this cause a problem in the fermentation process?

My first batch was fermenting fine but this batch the water is up way higher and I'm wondering if that's why I'm getting no bubbling so far.

Brewed yesterday, temp @pitch 65f. 
Yeast: Wyeast 1010 American Wheat

(Tried to upload picture wouldn't let me. But basically on the right side there is no water, it's all on the left side of the airlock way past the max level line)

Comment: It is normal for the water in the airlock to be pushed by the CO2 pressure, until a bubble forms and lets some air escape.  It is how the airlock works.

Answer (score 1):

The airlock level won't hurt anything.  It's fine.  Wait another 12-24 hours and I'll bet you'll have healthy fermentation happening.  If not, then add more yeast.  It's more likely to be impatience or possibly a yeast health issue.  My rule of thumb is about 36 hours before I begin to worry and add more yeast.

Comment: As further advice, always ignore the airlock. Whether it's bubbling or not doesn't tell you anything you need to know. The only reason it's there is to let gases out to prevent an explosion, while also keeping contaminants out. If it's bubbling, the only thing that tells you is that your lid is on tight, and there's some gas in there.